# How to use Facebook Like Button to Redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect, button, facebook-like

Im trying to use the Facebook like button to redirect onece it liked

im using standar configuration

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName`enter code here`(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<div id="fblike">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/example/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

And this part suppose to work to redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/post/id';
    }
);

</script>
```

But it doesnt work i got error (index):34 Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):34

and i try to init FB but not work.

Comment: why would you do that? the user should always be able to unlike, you should not redirect him. also, you can´t detect if the user liked or unliked something, both will result in a edge.create callback.

Comment: @luschn liking fires `edge.create`, unliking fires `edge.remove`. Agreed though on that one should not redirect, and present the button to the user at all times. Letting someone unlike something in the same place where they liked it is a matter of decency towards the user IMHO.

Comment: ah, yeah. i barely use those, thanx for the clarification.

Comment: either way, i don´t really see a question here. did you debug? did you check out the browser console?

Comment: that code doesnt work